# Angular click action with observable parameter

Tags: angular, observable

I have a question about the Observable, in my HTML, when i click on the button "RUN", it will call the function run() in ts:

```
@input application: Observable<Application>;

run() {
  this.application.subscribe(x => this.service.sendRequest(x.data.id););
}
```

Here i have a problem, because everytime when i update the application from another page, this sendRequest wii be trigged, and will run again.
Can you explain how to do this action, please?
I tried to do this:

```
    @input application: Observable<Application>;

    run() {
      const id = this.application.subscribe(() => map(res => 
{return x.data.id}));
      this.service.sendRequest(id);
    }
```

It doesn't work, because the id is null.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are subscribing to an observable. Meaning, every time the data of the observable changes, it will emit an update event to that observable, and output the new data.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but how to solve this problem, please?

Comment: Well what are you trying to do? What i mean is, what is your run button supposed to do?

Comment: I got the application data: Observable<Application>,  then i fill the HTML with this result async, then i click on the button with one of his parameter.

Comment: in fact, i want to call a web service with the id of application

Comment: run(id), where id is in the Observable<application> element.

Answer (score 0):

put your call of the service inside map:

```
run() {
this.application.subscribe(() => map(res => 
   {
      this.service.sendRequest(res.data.id);
   }
 ));
 }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it can not launch the sendRequest function.

Comment: if sendRequest make an http call you have to subscribe to it to launch it

Comment: i just send the call request without any return value, then i use the subject to receive the changement.

Comment: does the service return an observable?